# Undefined function 'syms' for input arguments of type 'char'

Tags: matlab

When I give,

```
  syms z
```

I end up getting,

```
Undefined function 'syms' for input arguments of type 'char'.
```

Can someone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You either don't have a license for the symbolic math toolbox or the toolbox is not installed.

Comment: Yeah, I don't have symbolic math toolbox, found that. Thanks Daniel :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found that I don't have the Symbolic Maths Toolbox needed for that.
It can be found by typing `ver` in the commandline.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @Samuel: I think this fully answers the question. Aditi tried to use a toolbox which is not available. Licensing and installing a toolbox is well documented, it's not really necessary to discuss this here.

Comment: Make sure you accept your own answer so that we know you don't need any more help with this issue.